# BGP community blackhole

Tags: cisco, routing, bgp, security

We have created peer with our ISP and my ISP send community to do backhole but how do i configure that and send community string for blackhole traffic.

ISP said use `64682:0` community for RTBH, I did following config but didn't work

```
router bgp 100
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 redistribute static route-map RTBH
 neighbor 71.xxx.xxx.61 remote-as 200
 neighbor 71.xxx.xxx.61 send-community
 network 70.xx.xx.0 mask 255.255.255.0


route-map RTBH permit 10
 match tag 666
 set community 64682:666

route-map RTBH permit 20
```

I am configured about `:0` in community because my router not accepting that.

here i am using route to send null.

`ip route 71.x.x.100 255.255.255.255 Null0 tag 666`

What i am doing wrong?

## EDIT:

I was following this Doc to setup community RTBH http://cenic.org/network/bgp-blackhole-community

## Update:

I have modify config with following info but still no luck and `no auto-summary` is default in BGP

```
route-map RTBH permit 10
 match tag 666
 set community 64682:0
 set ip next-hop 192.0.2.1
!
route-map RTBH permit 20
```

Debug info:

When i trigger null route i got following debug `debug ip routing` logs

```
R1#
*Jun 20 15:38:23.212: RT: updating static 70.xx.xx.1/32 (0x0)  :
    via 0.0.0.0 Nu0  0 1048578

*Jun 20 15:38:23.212: RT: rib update return code: 17
```

Comment: I had given you a link to the [Cisco document](http://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en_us/about/security/intelligence/blackhole.pdf) describing RTBH filtering. It explains in detail the options, and it includes configuration examples for the triggering router. Which configuration you use depends on what your ISP requires. If your ISP requires the community `64682:0`, then the community in your configuration, `64682:666` will not work.

Comment: So here i am confused, In all internet docs they use `ASN:666` and last `666` is they use for `match tag 666` so my question is, Do i need to match my tag and community last number after `:` ? That is why i use `:666`

Comment: You need to use the community which your ISP requires. That is the community that the ISP routers are looking for to trigger the black hole on its routers. Documents may use `:666` because it has an evil connotation, but you need to use what your ISP requires.

Comment: One additional comment: please describe the actual problems and provide error messages/debugging output instead of using terms like 'no luck' and 'didn't work'.

Comment: In debug i got this `RT: rib update return code: 17` I have updated my question too

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You should apply your route-map on BGP peer to send 
community attribute to your ISP by this command:

```
 neighbor {ip-address| group-name} route-map map-name {in | out}
```

applying route-map on `redistribute` is for filtering routes.

**EDIT:**
Look for other answers. They're definitely better than mine. :)

Comment: but what this `64682:0` community means? is it example or i has to be `ASN:NN` ?

Comment: It should be defined by your ISP. For BGP, it's just a label to apply certain configuration(e.g. MED) to routes that your ISP router received from your router.

Comment: Also I'm not sure why your ISP provided that example, maybe it'd work on some routers or switches? However I'm sure that applying BGP community route-map on peer will set attributes properly for your BGP routes.

Answer (score 1):

The Cisco documents provide a full explanation for the options, and examples of how to configure your router, depending on the ISP requirements. Be sure to read and understand the text. It explains what you need to do, and why you need to do it.

Here is a very good Cisco document, and an example of one way to do this (your ISP may not do it this way):

[REMOTELY TRIGGERED BLACK HOLE FILTERING — DESTINATION BASED AND SOURCE BASED](http://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en_us/about/security/intelligence/blackhole.pdf)

> **Trigger Router**
>
> This section provides a sample configuration listing for the trigger
>   router. In this configuration, peer groups are used because it is the
>   preferred way to configure a large number of BGP peers with similar
>   characteristics. You must set the send-community for all these peers
>   so they receive the noexport community and respect it by not
>   advertising this redistributed route to any of their external peers.
>
> Also, make sure to set no auto-summary so that specific host routes
>   can be black holed. Otherwise BGP will automatically summarize the
>   route based on class boundaries. Static routes are then redistributed
>   into BGP after applying the black hole-trigger route map.
>
> ```
> trigger#sh run
> Building configuration...
> version 12.1
> !
> hostname trigger
> !
> ip subnet-zero
> !
> interface Loopback0
>  ip address 192.168.255.245 255.255.255.255
> !
> interface Null0
>  no ip unreachables
> !
> interface Ethernet0/0
>  ip address 192.168.4.3 255.255.255.0
>  half-duplex
> !
> router ospf 100
>  log-adjacency-changes
>  redistribute connected subnets
>  network 192.168.4.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
> router bgp 740
>  no synchronization
>  bgp log-neighbor-changes
>  redistribute static route-map black-hole-trigger
>  neighbor black-hole peer-group
>  neighbor black-hole remote-as 740
>  neighbor black-hole update-source Loopback0
>  neighbor black-hole send-community
>  neighbor 192.168.255.246 remote-as 740
>  neighbor 192.168.255.246 update-source Loopback0
>  neighbor 192.168.255.253 peer-group black-hole
>  no auto-summary 
> !
> ip route 192.0.2.1 255.255.255.255 Null0
> route-map black-hole-trigger permit 10
>  match tag 66
>  set ip next-hop 192.0.2.1
>  set local-preference 200
>  set origin igp
>  set community no-export
> !
> route-map black-hole-trigger deny 25
> !
> no scheduler allocate
> end
> ```
>
> The last part of this configuration creates a route map to match the
>   route tag 66 and sets route characteristics. A higher value of local
>   preference is desired for choosing a route, so it is set to 200, which
>   is greater than the default value of 100. Also, to make sure that
>   other static routes are not affected by this route map, a deny
>   statement is placed at the end.

Comment: In your example should i use `set community 64682:0` in route-map? and `set ip next-hop 192.0.2.1` ?

Comment: The example address, `192.0.1.2`, is just an example. You would use the address for your network. I think you really need to read the whole document and understand how this works. This is one example of one way of doing this. There are a couple of way to do it, and you need to do the one which your ISP requires.

Comment: I did setup whole network in GNS and it was working in GNS lab but i tested without community setting. But now in real world i have this community stuff which is driving me crazy..

Comment: That's because your ISP is using a different method to trigger the black hole than what you tested. The document explains how the community-based RTBH works, and gives you an example configuration. You should understand what the ISP is doing (the document explains that). This will help you understand how you need to configure your side.

Comment: Problem solved, This is crazy! Currently device attached to Router so i was trying to send null route for Router LAN side interface and they didn't work but as soon as i attached dummy server to router and send host IP address it works! It doesn't mention anywhere in Document

Comment: You need to use the destination address of the device suffering from the attack. That is whatever address is the destination address in the attacking packets. Your router interface is not the destination of the attack, but the server is.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you configure "neighbor  send-community" the communities attached to the prefix won't be sent to the neighbor.

Comment: Hey i have added `neighbor send-community` command in config but no luck. you can see my updated answer